# Who am I to Puzzlevania?

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme, story

I woke up this morning on the grass outside of the walls of Puzzlevania. I had a terrible headache and couldn't remember anything. I had a feeling that I was someone important for the country, so I tried to ask a guard by the gate to let me in.
He ignored me at first, but as I insisted, he told me to get out and stop disturbing the celebrations of election of a new ruler in Puzzlevania.
Confused by the guard's behaviour I asked him to tell me who am I and why he is so unfriendly. As most of Puzzlevanians never answer questions straight forward, he told me the following riddle:

> Go by your heart to know right direction
>   Don't split your father from dissertation
>   A symbol comes in if decimated
>   You said your thanks - leave it unrelated
>
> Having them two, both need your completion
>   End them to see your current position.
>   The first ends with french great water with waves
>   The second completes with anger and rave

Given the riddle above, can you tell me what is my "current position"? Why I feel important to Puzzlevania?

For clarification: The answer should explain my relationship to the country of Puzzlevania.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Final guess (thanks to @Gareth for clues)
Go by your heart to know right direction

> Hint is LEFT because our heart is on the left

Don't split your father from dissertation

> Father = PARENT, dissertation = THESIS, put them together and get PARENTHESIS

A symbol comes in if decimated

> LEFT PARENTHESIS symbol "(" decimated means take the ASCII (**A** **S**ymbol **C**omes **I**n **I**f decimated) value in base 10 which is "40", spells out next hint: FORTY

You said your thanks - leave it unrelated

> Thanks could be TY meaning Thank you, so separate FORTY into FOR and TY

Having them two, both need your completion

> The two hints are FOR and TY

End them to see your current position.
The first ends with french great water with waves

> FOR + MER = former

The second completes with anger and rave

> TY+RANT = Tyrant

So the answer is

> Former Tyrant

Comment: You have some good points, but it is not the right solution. Btw, your spoiler marks do not work.

Comment: Yes i don't know why though

Comment: I had the same opinion about the first word. The second could equally end RANT or RAGE. I haven't thought of any really good candidates for it yet (nor had I thought of yours). Your spoilers are OK now.

Comment: I also wonder whether "anger and rave" might indicate "roar" and the second word end with a homophonous -ror (there being an obvious candidate word with that ending), but that seems a bit inelegant since there's nothing to indicate a homophone. I fear we're going to have to figure out the first stanza, which looks much harder than the second.

Comment: Indeed.. though there is a good candidate word ending with RANT

Comment: Oh, so there is. How did I miss it?

Comment: And its beginning seems to link nicely to the last line of the first stanza.

Comment: And splitting Pa from paper gives per, which is Latin for "for"? Hmmm. That would make the third line about the symbol just dressing.

Comment: I don't like "paper" = "dissertation", but I suppose it's possible. Is the first line just decoration too?

Comment: I see Joe has a different way of getting the first half of the first word. It's ingenious but to my mind even less plausible than paper minus pa.

Comment: Every line in first stanza contains a message without which you should not be able to obtain a complete answer.

Comment: The other thing I dislike about PAPER minus PA is that the clue explicitly says "don't" :-).

Comment: @Joe's 2nd answer: 1st line has a meaning, 2nd - agreed with Gareth's comment - you are told not to split it.

Comment: The 2nd Joe's answer (the two words) to the riddle is actually correct, but I would like to accept it after there is a proper explanation why. (@Joe which you are not that far from)

Comment: Ok tried some new explanations !

Comment: You're almost there. Only 3 first lines are incorrect and 1st part of the 3rd line should result from the first two. I have to do this - its not PAPER.

Comment: Think I got it this time !!!

Comment: That looks extremely convincing. Well done!

Comment: Yes! That's it! Additionally, you missed a little clue in 3rd line which I'll add to your answer as edit :)